# Full text search in PostgreSQL with "to_tsvector" for all columns

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I am adding one column in table to create index for search with to_tsvector.

My question is how can I mention all comumns in  to_tsvector(**?**).

I know by using all names in to_tsvector(Column1 ||""||Column2||""||Column3......); it can be done.

In case of 50+ columns its difficult to write name of each column, so how to write to_tsvector(?) in short so by default all comaumns are considered for to_tsvector.

```
ALTER TABLE from "POC1_Schema"."POC1_Table"
ADD COLUMN document tsvector;

UPDATE from "POC1_Schema"."POC1_Table"
SET document= to_tsvector(Column1|| ' ' ||Column2|| ' ' ||Column3|| ' ' ||Column4|| ' ' ||Column5|| ' ' ||Column6);

CREATE INDEX document_idx
  ON "POC1_Schema"."POC1_Table"
  USING GIN (document_with_idx);

select *
from from "POC1_Schema"."POC1_Table"
where document @@ to_tsquery('READY');
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: but you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: As you will probably do that in a trigger, what is the problem with 50+ column? You only need to list them once. You _could_ try `to_tsvector("POC1_Table"::text)` but that creates a different text representation than your concatenation (which btw: will result in `null` if one only column is `null`)

Comment: Thanks. That was most useful and gretely helped me. I really appreasite your inputs @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey, @a_horse_with_no_name, Your help was most useful for me. I came across one issue where to_tsvector("POC1_Table"::text) does not work with NULL values. (ts_vector is not created is any one NULL is there in that row). Then, I used document = to_tsvector(coalesce(CAST (COL1 as text),'') || ' ' || coalesce( COL2 ,'')). Here COL1 is integer so need coalesce CAST and where COL2 is text. This will work even any value is NULL. Do you know any better way to convert integer, bigint, binary values in ts_vector?